# Can we have partition key and sort key on same column in a nosql db like dynamodb?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Considering i have following columns in a table ->
unique_url , postText, expiryTime, creationTime

and i want to partition my table in a no sql database like dynamo db on unique_url column. So now whnever i query db that i need the record with this unique_url , it will first create a hash on this unique_url then find the partition in which it is stored, then after this it will go to that partition and search for that unique_url by scannin gall the records.

I also want to sort the table based on this unique_url column so that this query runs fast, can i also specify sort key as unique_url?

I havent find any resource on web that says that we can or cannot have same column used as partition key and same column as sort key.

Comment: you need to pass a dictionary through put_item() so I don't believe you can have the partition key and sort key named the same thing or the dictionary won't be correct. naming the sortkey unique_url_sort and passing the same value for both might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `unique_url` as the partition key, you can't have it also be the sort key.  Nor do you need it to be.

with just a hash as the primary key, you can use `GetItem()` to return whatever single record you need.